# i got problem in snmp walk

Tags: command-line

```
malik@ubuntu:~$ sudo cfgmaker –output=/etc/mrtg/mrtg.cfg public@192.168.1.9
--base: Get Device Info on public@–output=/etc/mrtg/mrtg.cfg:
Error:
  can't resolve "–output=/etc/mrtg/mrtg.cfg" to IP address
 at /usr/share/perl5/SNMP_util.pm line 428.
SNMPWALK Problem for public@–output=/etc/mrtg/mrtg.cfg::::::v4only
 at /usr/bin/cfgmaker line 960.
WARNING: Skipping public@–output=/etc/mrtg/mrtg.cfg: as no info could be retrieved

--base: Get Device Info on public@192.168.1.9:
SNMP Error:
no response received
SNMPv1_Session (remote host: "192.168.1.9" [192.168.1.9].161)
                  community: "public"
                 request ID: -480330141
                PDU bufsize: 8000 bytes
                    timeout: 2s
                    retries: 5
                    backoff: 1)
 at /usr/share/perl5/SNMP_util.pm line 629.
SNMPWALK Problem for 1.3.6.1.2.1.1 on public@192.168.1.9::::::v4only
 at /usr/bin/cfgmaker line 960.
WARNING: Skipping public@192.168.1.9: as no info could be retrieved

Use of uninitialized value $comment_sysdescr in substitution (s///) at /usr/bin/cfgmaker line 384.
Use of uninitialized value $sysname in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/cfgmaker line 417.
Use of uninitialized value $comment_sysdescr in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/cfgmaker line 417.
Use of uninitialized value $syscontact in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/cfgmaker line 417.
Use of uninitialized value $syslocation in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/cfgmaker line 417.
Use of uninitialized value $comment_sysdescr in substitution (s///) at /usr/bin/cfgmaker line 384.
Use of uninitialized value $sysname in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/cfgmaker line 417.
Use of uninitialized value $comment_sysdescr in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/cfgmaker line 417.
Use of uninitialized value $syscontact in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/cfgmaker line 417.
Use of uninitialized value $syslocation in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/bin/cfgmaker line 417.
# Created by 
# /usr/bin/cfgmaker –output=/etc/mrtg/mrtg.cfg public@192.168.1.9


### Global Config Options

#  for UNIX
# WorkDir: /home/http/mrtg

#  for Debian
WorkDir: /var/www/mrtg

#  or for NT
# WorkDir: c:\mrtgdata

### Global Defaults

#  to get bits instead of bytes and graphs growing to the right
# Options[_]: growright, bits

EnableIPv6: no

######################################################################
# System: 
# Description: 
# Contact: 
# Location: 
######################################################################



######################################################################
# System: 
# Description: 
# Contact: 
# Location: 
######################################################################
```

Comment: A little more description would not hurt. OS, versions and config for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
–output=/etc/mrtg/mrtg.cfg
```

with

```
--output=/etc/mrtg/mrtg.cfg
```